# send formdata as json to an angularjs application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, json

There is a webpage, build on AngularJS with a login.

I need to iframe it on my page, and autologin my users on the site.
looking at the angularJS Site, the login procedure is awaiting a json object.

I tried several ways. Submitting an array, creating a json object in js and send it. But nothing works.

The json must look like this:

```
{
  'TAKE':{
        'username': 'whatever',
        'password': 'whatever'
    }
}
```

the closest solution i had, was to create a json via js and send it with the form. The problem was, that in the request, symbols like {} and ' " was coded like:

```
%22%3A%7B%22
```

The JS i used:

```
function submitAsJSON(form) {

    var json = "{'TAKE':{'username': 'whatever','password': 'whatever'}}";
    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(json);

    var newForm = "<form method='POST'  action='" + $(form).attr('action') + "'>" +
    "<input name='" + JSONString + "'>" +
    "</form>"
    $(newForm).appendTo('body').submit();
   }
```

also looking at the headers in chrome, its awaiting:

```
content-type: application/json
```

but i am sending:

```
Content-Type: application/xml;
```

How can i send a json and let the user automatically log in?

Comment: Some of the code that you tried would be really helpfull in tracking the problem down.

Comment: i edited the js in my question

Comment: How about submitting the form directly:  `form.submit()`

Comment: the application only accepts json per Post, so submitting just the form would just send them as an array

Comment: I would add that `var JSONString = JSON.stringify(json);` looks really strange in this instance - your `json` var is already a string. Why are you stringifying a string is a mystery. Your  `json` var itself is almost valid stringified json, if it would be like `json = {\"username\":\"test\",\"password\":\"test\"}` then it would be valid, stringified json, which you can parse

Comment: i know it makes not much sense but i was trying a lot of stuff and different ways. My plan was to take the data from the form. But then i changed my mind and wrote it in js to test it. Nothing works. Cause at the end, its not sending it as a json

Comment: i think i know where the problem is. i am sending Content-Type: application/xml, but its awaiting Content-Type: application/json

Comment: It's also a problem. Consearning your test js - `json` var had an extra, un needed stringify. A small example `var json = {'username':'test', 'password':'test'};var test=JSON.stringify(json);JSON.parse(test)`. Notice - `json` var looks a bit different, also only a single `stringify` is needed to create a parceble, stringified json. `JSON.parse(test)` is just showing that `test` can and will be parced

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you to convert form data into JSON.
For autologin you will have to handle that on serve side:

`var formData = JSON.stringify($("#theFormID").serializeArray());`